# typehead of bootstrap only show 8 records

Tags: bootstrap-typeahead

[image]

hello can any one guide me in my ajax request its always show me only eight record .

```
$(this).typeahead({
    source: function (query, process) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: url + "/ajax/productdetail",
            type: 'GET',
            limit: 10,
            data: {
                cat: $type,
                name: query,
                form: $form,
                setupid: $setupid
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                objects = [];
                map = {};
                $.each(response, function (i, object) {
                    //debugger;
                    map[object.name] = object;
                    objects.push(object.name);
                });
                process(objects);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

[image: snapshort for suggestion![][1]]

Comment: Can you provide a demo of the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Just add an option "items" while instantiating the typeahead method. Hope the below sample will help you to understand.

```
$('input#auto-complete-field').typeahead({
    minLength : 0,
    items: 9999,
    source: function (query, process) {
        objects = [];
        map = {};
        $.ajax({
            .......
            ...... 
        });
    }
    updater: function(item) {
        .............
        .............
    }
});
```